# Diazo transfer to 1,3-dicarbonyl with tosyl azide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

[image: Reaction scheme]

What is the mechanism for the above reaction?

Comment: 3+2 cycloaddition and retro-cyclo maybe but I'm not sure.

Comment: (I removed the fluff so that it's easier for future readers.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This starting material is not actually an enone; it is a 1,3-dicarbonyl, confusingly drawn as the enol tautomer. 1,3-Dicarbonyls are mildly acidic ($\mathrm pK_\mathrm a \sim 10$) and can be deprotonated by weak bases, such as triethylamine ($\mathrm pK_\mathrm a \sim 9$), which was mentioned in the question. So, now, we have an enolate ion which is *nucleophilic*.

Tosyl azide, $\ce{TsN3}$, is an odd reagent. It's easy to think that it is acting as a nucleophile of some sort, because the azide ion is nucleophilic, but actually it is an *electrophile*.

[image: Mechanism - part 1]

The next part is the removal of the formyl group, which is a bit tricky. Here I am not 100% sure, so take it with a pinch of salt, but I think Mith was on the right track with the retro-(3+2) cycloaddition. This is my guess:

[image: Mechanism - part 2]

In fact, the cyclisation of the terminal nitrogen onto a carbonyl group has been proposed before, in mechanistic studies of electrophilic azidation by D. A. Evans.<sup>1</sup> That makes me feel a bit more confident in my guess!

[image: Proposed triazoline formation]

Anyway, the product above is simply a resonance form of the diazo product you want.

[image: Mechanism - part 3]

---

**Reference**

1. Evans, D. A.; Britton, T. C.; Ellman, J. A.; Dorow, R. L. The asymmetric synthesis of α-amino acids. Electrophilic azidation of chiral imide enolates, a practical approach to the synthesis of (*R*)- and (*S*)-α-azido carboxylic acids. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1990,** *112* (10), 4011–4030. [DOI: 10.1021/ja00166a045](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00166a045). Non-paywall version available from the [Evans group website](http://evans.rc.fas.harvard.edu/pdf/evans126.pdf).